# Subset proof, show A⊆B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

So I was reviewing this question and Im lost on how to do this question, and Ive seen to of misplaced the notes. The question is as follows:
if  **(A ∩ C) ⊆ (B ∩ C)** and **(A ∩ C̅) ⊆ (B ∩ C̅)**

then **A ⊆ B**

My attempt so far:

```
(x∈A ∩ x∈C) ⊆ (x∈B ∩ x∈C)  
(x∈A ∩ x∉C) ⊆ (x∈B ∩ x∉C)

Since x∉C and x∈C => ∅ 

(x∈A ∩ ∅) ⊆ (x∈B ∩ ∅)
(x∈A) ⊆ (x∈B ∩ ∅)
A⊆B
```

I think this is correct though Im a bit rusty and not sure if this is correct

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram to help you understand the problem.

Comment: $x \in A$ (and the like) are assertions, not sets.  I'm not familiar with how you're combining these assertions with set intersection $\cap$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a\in A$. Then either $a\in C$ or $a\in C^\complement$. If $a\in C$, then $a\in A\cap C$ and therefore $a\in B\cap C$; in particular, $a\in B$. And if $a\in C^\complement$, then $a\in A\cap C^\complement$ and therefore $a\in B\cap C^\complement$; in particular, $a\in B$, again.

Concerning your proof, I don't understand the sentence “Since $x\notin C$ and $x\in C\implies\emptyset$”.

Comment: so since a∈C or a∈ not C we can cancel the C portions out? Still lost how do we get to the final answer

Comment: Either $a\in C$ or $a\in C^\complement$ and, in both cases, $a\in B$. If there's a passage that you don't understand, please tell me which one.

Comment: I understand it a bit more in either case we have a∈B  regardless of if a is in C, thus the C portion is ignored. Is this correct

Comment: I did not ignore it. I proved that if $a\in C$ then $a\in B$ and if $a\in C^\complement$, then $a\in B$ too.

Comment: Yes I see and understand that, with that in mind what happens to the a∈C and a∈ not C  part? 
Is it this: (x∈A ∩ x∉C) ⊆ (x∈B ∩ x∉C)  and since Either a∈C or a∈ not C, in both cases a∈B and a∈A thus  (x∈A) ⊆ (x∈B)

Comment: I don't even know what that means. If there is some part of my answer that you do not understand, feel free to tell me so.

Comment: The portion where I am lost at is after you show "Either a∈C or a∈ Not C and, in both cases, a∈B". Is this the correct work? https://i.gyazo.com/3aa11e9c0434a145083f2d42bc837877.png

Comment: I suggested you to tell me which part of my **answer** you failed to understand. The sentence that you quoted was written in a comment. It is **not** part of my answer.

Comment: the last portion " in particular, a∈B" and "in particular, a∈B, again."

Comment: Since $B\cap C\subset B$, if $a\in B\cap C$, then $a\in B$. And, since $B\cap C^\complement\subset B$, if $a\in B\cap C^\complement$, then $a\in B$.

Comment: why is it  a∈B∩C, then a∈B

Comment: Because, as I wrote in my previous comment, $B\cap C\subset B$.

Comment: ok i see that, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I understand your attempt. Let me outline a simple proof for you:

Let $x\in A$. Then, we know that either $x\in A\cap C$ or $x\in A\cap\overline{C}$. Using this fact, the hypothesis give us that either $x\in B\cap C$ or $x\in B\cap \overline{C}$. Therefore, $x\in B$ and hence $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: I get confused near the end, how do you know after applying the hypothesis x∈B and thus  A⊆B.

Comment: Because we conclude that either $x\in B\cap C$ or $x\in B\cap\overline{C}$ and in both cases we have $x\in B$.